# MYSQL Inner Join Sort By Ascending DateTime

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm writing a query to get all customer information and display the last time they ordered. My current query is:

```
SELECT
`user`.fname,
`user`.lname,
`user`.email,
`order`.orderplaced_ts,
COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM `order`
INNER JOIN `user` ON `order`.user_id = `user`.id
WHERE `order`.store_id = 10
AND `order`.orderplaced_ts > "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
AND `order`.order_status != "Cancelled"
GROUP BY `order`.user_id
ORDER BY `order`.orderplaced_ts
```

I've tried ASC and DESC after the `ORDER BY order.orderplaced_ts` but that's still not returning what I want.

EDIT: Current Results

```
First   Last         Email                  Date                  Count
Lisa    Day          email@something.com    2015-01-08 13:16:31    105
Alex    Sullivan     email@something.com    2015-01-05 11:48:33    90
Jill    GORDON       email@something.com    2015-01-02 12:52:57    68
Bob     Jain         email@something.com    2015-03-23 12:39:24    62
Jack    Merkher      email@something.com    2015-01-05 11:19:31    56
```

The Date field is displaying the first time they ordered, while what I want is the last time they ordered.

Desired Results would be:

```
    First   Last         Email                  Date                  Count
    Lisa    Day          email@something.com    2015-07-08 13:16:31    105
    Alex    Sullivan     email@something.com    2015-07-05 11:48:33    90
    Jill    GORDON       email@something.com    2015-07-02 12:52:57    68
    Bob     Jain         email@something.com    2015-07-23 12:39:24    62
    Jack    Merkher      email@something.com    2015-07-05 11:19:31    56
```

Sample Data from SELECT * :

```
ID      User_ID Store_ID    orderplaced_ts
1104121 214831  10          2015-01-02 11:04:49
1104261 559281  10          2015-01-02 11:21:34
1104791 420461  10          2015-01-02 12:10:34
1105041 801481  10          2015-01-02 12:33:58
1105051 216501  10          2015-01-02 12:35:28
1105191 814661  10          2015-01-02 12:42:26
1105241 304571  10          2015-01-02 12:44:31
1105321 781611  10          2015-01-02 12:52:41
1105331 528411  10          2015-01-02 12:52:57
1105641 752171  10          2015-01-02 13:36:10
1106061 458791  10          2015-01-02 15:46:24
```

So what i'm trying to do is get all the users, how many times they ordered and what is the most recent order that they have placed.

The Inner Join is just to retrieve the user email, first name, and last name.

My Final Query that resolved the issue looked as follows:

```
SELECT
    `user`.fname,
    `user`.lname,
    `user`.email,
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Orders,
    `order`.orderplaced_ts AS First_Order,
    MAX(order.orderplaced_ts) AS Last_Order
FROM `order`
INNER JOIN `user` ON `order`.user_id = `user`.id
WHERE `order`.store_id = 10
AND `order`.orderplaced_ts > "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
AND `order`.order_status != "Cancelled"
GROUP BY `order`.user_id ASC
ORDER BY `order`.orderplaced_ts
```

Comment: `asc` is generally the default sort order, so if you want the most recent orderplaced_ts to show up FIRST in there results, it'd HAVE to be `desc`.

Comment: How is it wrong?  Can you provide example data, desired results, and actual results?

Comment: have you tried MAX(`order`.orderplaced_ts)?  I think Meoiswa is right below and you should be using the aggregation functions instead of trying to sort by orderplaced_ts

Comment: @mjr Thank you, I got it - brain fart! I accepted his answer as it lead me in the right direction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your selected values that are not in the `Group By` clause **must** have an aggregation function like `sum` or `max`.
Otherwise the grouped selection will not be able to know which value to display.

I'd suggest grouping your rows by `user.fname`, `user.lname` and `user.email` instead of `order.user_id`

As per @Uueerdo 's comment: Ordering by `MAX(order.orderplaced_ts)` will do the trick

Comment: Considering he is (effectively) grouping on the primary key of user, the GROUP BY should be fine; but he probably should be querying for and ordering by `MAX(order.orderplaced_ts)`

Comment: @Uueerdo - Thank You! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Uueerdo Maybe you should post it as an answer <3

Comment: @Meoiswa nah, it's fine, I don't have the time to write up a complete one.